# Can the 4 inner sheaths be destroyed upon Self-realization?

Tags: advaita, upanishads

We all know that the physical body or annamaya kosha perishes. But what about the 4 inner sheaths like, pranamaya, manomaya, vijnanamaya and anandamaya koshas. Do they perish when moksha is attained? Are there any scriptural verses that says they perish upon moksha?

I'm interested only in answers from advaitic/non-dual perspective.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes on Moksha all the koshas are perished. But that is Videha mukti. In Jeevan Mukti only Anandamaya Kosha is destroyed. The four other remian.

Comment: Are there any verses in upanishads or brahma sutras which says all koshas are destroyed on videha mukti? ... And why is the anandamaya kosha (causal body) destroyed in jivan mukti? ... I thought as long you're living in this world you need all the 5 koshas.

Comment: I don't know the scripture, I listened to Swamiji in YouTube who was follower of Advaitha. If all the 5 koshas are intact what's the difference between normal person and Jivan muktha?? In Jivan Muktha karana shareera gets destroyed, that's hiw Jivan muktha becomes Jivan muktha. On Videha mukti or final mukti all koshas are destroyed.

Comment: https://youtu.be/Rjh6ls244NM its authentic but it is in Kannada, you may not know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a verse in scripture, Prasna Upanishad VI.5, that supports the idea that a person who has attained Advaita moksha becomes Brahman only.

> He created prana; from prana faith, space, air, fire, water, earth,
> the organs, mind, food; from food virility, austerity, the Vedic
> hymns, sacrifice, the worlds; and the in the worlds He created names.

**Prasna Upanishad VI.4**

> Space ... Earth: These elements of matter constitute the body, through
> which the fruit of action is experienced.
>
> Organs: Both the organs of perception and the organs of action.
>
> Mind: The leader of organs.
>
> The sixteen parts are created through avidya. These created entities
> are unreal, like the objects seen in a dream. After the destruction of
> avidya they again merge in the Purusha, losing their name and forms.

**The Upanishad by Swami Nikhilananda**

> As these flowing rivers, bound for the ocean, disappear into the ocean
> after having reached it, their names and forms being destroyed, and
> are called simply the ocean - **even so, these sixteen parts of the
> seer, whose goal is the Purusha, disappear into the Purusha after
> having reached Him, their names and forms being destroyed, and are
> called simply the Purusha. He becomes free of parts and immortal.**  On
> this there is the following verse:

**Prasna Upanishad VI.5**

> The following is adopted from Sankara's commentary: The Purusha,
> though in reality without parts, appears to have parts when
> conditioned, through avidya, by the sixteen parts which are its
> upadhis. In order that the Purusha may be realized in His
> unconditioned form, through the elimination, by means of knowledge, of
> the parts falsely superimposed upon Him, the parts are said to have
> originated from Him. The Purusha (Brahman) is completely
> undifferentiated, pure, and non-dual; Its relationship, causal or
> otherwise, with prana and the rest is not possible, without false
> superposition. That is why, through ignorance alone, the parts are
> seen to arise form, exist in, and disappear into the Purusha.

**The Upanishad by Swami Nikhilananda**

Comment: The mind spoken here must be manomaya and vijnanamaya koshas, isn't it? ... And does the Anandamaya kosha (causal body) comes under the mind as well?

Comment: I don't think casual body is part of the mind. However, no kosha survives after death of a person who has attained moksha. That person becomes Brahman only and is free of parts.